# What is a uploadable maximum file size?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-data-management

I tries uploading 200MB Solid works format file, and it worked out.
Don't consider request timeout issue. I will extend it to 30min

How about 500MB or 1GB?
If I can upload 500MB solid works file(or assmembly files), I'm happy.
If I can upload 1GB solid works file, I'm supper happy.

Comment: There is no upload size limitation.

What is your developer account status? There is a storage limit for the trial account, but it's 5GB in total. See https://aps.autodesk.com/pricing

Comment: And which endpoint you used to upload the 1GB file? Old upload endpoints like [PUT buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectKey](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-PUT/), [PUT buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectKey/resumable](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-resumable-PUT/), please use the Direct-S3 endpoints instead. See https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-upload-and-download-sdks

Comment: I bought Flex token, not free plan. I'm using a new endpoint: "#{AUTODESK_API_URL}/oss/v2/buckets/#{bucket_key}/objects/#{object_key}/signeds3upload?minutesExpiration=30&useAcceleration=true" Is this correct setting?

Comment: If so, please change the query string parameter `parts` to a higher value (e.g. 5) to get upload links for resumable uploading. Its default value is 1, so you will get one upload link only. Then it might easily timeout when uploading a large model.

Comment: like this?: "#{AUTODESK_API_URL}/oss/v2/buckets/#{bucket_key}/objects/#{object_key}/signeds3upload?minutesExpiration=30&useAcceleration=true&parts=5"

Comment: Yelp, that is it.